# Google Desktop Search replacement for Windows

Tags: windows, search-engine, text-search, search

Before [Google discontinued it in 2010 on dubious grounds](http://googlesystem.blogspot.ro/2010/09/10-reasons-why-google-desktop-will-be.html) I used Google Desktop Search, had a few plugins, and I liked the fact that it could be accessed by browser and also you could browse a text version of the indexed document.

Although [I found the old versions](http://www.oldversion.com/windows/google-desktop/), they no longer work.

Is there a Google Desktop Search replacement for Windows that works pretty much like GDS used to?

Answer (score 9):

After a few days of [trying and surveying desktop searching alternatives, although not mentioned on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_search_engines#Desktop_search_engines) I found the [Regain opensource project](http://regain.sourceforge.net/index.php) which shares most of the Google Desktop Search options and is also opensource and still in development ([full features list here](http://regain.sourceforge.net/features.php)).

**Short Description**

Regain is a Java search engine based on Jakarta Lucene. It provides indexing and searching files for plenty of formats (HTML,XML,doc(x),xls(x),ppt(x),oo,PDF,RTF,mp3,mp4,Java). A TagLibrary eases integrating search results in your JSP based web page.

**Main features in common with GDS being:**

- web server
- tray icon
- cached version of the indexed file
- search keywords
- can support additional formats (regain supports I-Filter)

  [image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can try [Lookeen](http://www.lookeen.com). Since Version 10 it is a pure desktop search and has a free "lite" version.

Disclaimer: I’m a part of the company that developed Lookeen.

Comment: My experience with Lookeen has not  been very good: https://software4scholars.wordpress.com/2018/02/10/lookeen-and-x1-search-suck-everything-just-works/

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple other desktop search applications. I've found this list from Wikipedia very exhaustive but I've found that [Copernic](http://www.copernic.com/en/products/desktop-search/) and [Lookeen](http://lookeen.com/) offer the most complete as free version. You can however use a file search if you do not want to search emails. It always depends on what you are looking for on your computer and which other productivity tools you use.