# Software to search through files (mostly PDF)

Tags: open-source, windows-7, pdf, search, text-search

I would like to know if there are some active open source projects to develop alternatives to [Google Desktop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Desktop) or [Regain](http://regain.sourceforge.net/index.php) for Windows 7.

**The situation is the following:**

- I have a folder full of PDF documents (organised in many subfolders). There is a least one document updated or created every day,
- I often need to search some words and sentences in these documents,
- Windows search and Agent Ransack are too slow and their interfaces do not suit my needs,
- The interface of Regain suits my needs almost perfectly: I type my search criteria and I get a list of result with a short overview, but I can't restrict the search perimeter to a specific directory,
- The last update to regain was on 2014-07-30 - this makes me wonder if it is outdated or uses obsolete components (and I wouldn't want to compromise the security of my computer),
- I searched on many websites before posting here ([This topic](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/11513/google-desktop-search-replacement-for-windows) led me to Regain).

Here is an example of search results with Regain:
[image: Regain: example of search results]

Answer (score 2):

I used to use Recoll and it was very neat: http://www.lesbonscomptes.com/recoll/
It uses poppler, the well-known PDF library.

Modern OS often have such search features by default, for instance Fedora provides Nepomuk. They can be very resource-intensive, though.

Comment: Thanks! I failed to mention though: the software needs to run on Windows. I updated my post to add the missing information.

Comment: Oh. Maybe someone will do a port. Apparently Poppler is available in Windows too, so that's one thing less to worry about.

Comment: Recoll now has an almost native port to windows; see the news at http://www.lesbonscomptes.com/recoll/ ... you might have to compile from source. Stay tuned for an installer, it's likely on its way.

Answer (score 1):

From Brian Z.'s [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/597810): [DocFetcher](http://docfetcher.sourceforge.net/en/index.html) is a cross-platform solution under Eclipse Public License and seems very powerful judging from the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Anyway you mentioned that you have all the documents arranged in folders, in that case, try Adobe Reader's advance search feature.

Once you have opened the Adobe reader, Shift+Ctrl+F should bring up the interface [ or you can navigate by Edit(menu) -> Advance Search ]
I noticed that for Regain you are running a server ( it must be a light weight one, but still its an extra process )
Screenshot is from Adobe Reader XI version. 
[image: Advance Search Interface]